# Serialization error in MongoDb Dictionary property using RegEx

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to do this filter:

```
var query = myCollection.AsQueryable();

var regex = new Regex("^Foo");

query = query.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x.User["FullName"].ToString())); <---- Error here!
```

With this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays)] //Tryied also Dynamic, Document, ArrayOfDcouments
    public Dictionary<string, object> User { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: x.User.get_Item("FullName").ToString().
```

Can someone help me?

**Update**

Debugging Driver source code I found something strange. In `BsonSerializationInfoFinder` class, `node.Method.Name` must be  `ElementAt` or `get_Item` while in this case it is `ToString` and it returns null raising the exception!

```
protected override BsonSerializationInfo VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        switch (node.Method.Name)
        {
            case "ElementAt":
                return VisitElementAt(node);
            case "get_Item":
                return VisitGetItem(node);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open implementation ticket on the driver project:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-917